# How can I iterate through a list of links with Scriban?

Tags: scriban

I've created a template in Sitecore, and one of the fields in my template allows me to select an existing Link List item.  I also have a Scriban variant where the code loops through all the items created with that template.  When I try to output the Link List field, I only get the name of the list, rather than the list of links.  How can I display the actual list of links?

```
    <!-- loop through the parent items -->
{{ for i_parent in i_datasource.children }}                     

    <!--loop through the child items -->
    {{ for i_child in i_parent.children }}   
            
        <!-- link -->
        {{ if (i_child.Link) }}
            <p class="linkstyle">{{i_child.Link}}</p> 
        {{end}}

        <!-- description -->
        {{ if (i_child.Description) }}
            <p class="description"> {{i_child.Description}}</p>
        {{end}}

        <!-- link  list -->
        {{ if (i_child.LinkList) }}
            <!-- this displays the list name -->
            {{i_child.LinkList}}      

            <!-- TO DO: display the list of links, not just the link list name -->
            {{ for i_product in (sc_followmany i_item i_child.LinkList) }} 
                <!-- this displays nothing -->
                <span class="linkstyle">{{i_product.name}}</span>
            {{end}}
        {{end}}

    {{ end }} 

{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the sc_followmany with the wrong parameters. It needs these:

- Item for which the value of the field is retrieved
- Name of the field that links to items

(see https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html)

I your case that would be `sc_followmany i_child "LinkList"` or use the (shorter) extension like this: `i_child.LinkList.targets`

Comment: It's still not displaying anything.  I tried {{ for i_product in (sc_followmany i_child "LinkList") }}  and {{ for i_product in i_child.LinkList.targets }} .  It's not even going into the loop.  Could it be a problem with the list?

Comment: Is LinkList actually the name of your field? And which type is that field?

Comment: Yes, the field is named "LinkList" type is Droplist, source is "/sitecore/content/MyTenant/MySite/Data/Link Lists"

Comment: Oh, a DropList.. that won't work. A droplist stores the names of the selected items, and not a link (guid) to it. You should use a droplink field instead.